# Multiple Duplicate in my query using inner join

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query, maybe you can help me.

I have this data , check

1. Trans_lhphd (a)
   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1cef6/2
2. Trans_lhpdthp (b)
   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d528e/1

This is my query :

```
SELECT
SUM(
    IF (a.IdShift = '1', a.Planning, 0)
) AS Shift1,
SUM(
    IF (a.IdShift = '2', a.Planning, 0)
) AS Shift2,
SUM(

    IF (a.IdShift = '3', a.Planning, 0)
) AS Shift3,
SUM(a.Planning) AS total,
SUM(
    IF (
        b.IdShift = '1',
        b.QtyProduksi,
        0
    )
) AS Shift1a,
SUM(
    IF (
        b.IdShift = '2',
        b.QtyProduksi,
        0
    )
) AS Shift2a,
SUM(
    IF (
        b.IdShift = '3',
        b.QtyProduksi,
        0
    )
) AS Shift3a
FROM
    trans_lhphd a INNER JOIN trans_lhpdthp b ON
        b.IdBukti= a.IdBukti
WHERE
    a.DivisiId = 'DI070' AND
    b.HasilProduksi = 'Good' AND
    a.Tanggal BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND
    '2017-10-16'
GROUP BY
    a.Tanggal
```

According with my query, the result like this :

```
| Shift1|Shift2|Shift3|total|Shift1a|Shift2a|Shift3a|
|-------|------|------|-----|-------|------ |-------|
|  4000 | 1200 |1210  |6410 |310    |450    |120    |
|  1000 |  0   |0     |1000 |500    |0      |0      |
```

And I want to The result must be

```
    | Shift1|Shift2|Shift3|total|Shift1a|Shift2a|Shift3a|
    |-------|------|------|-----|-------|------ |-------|
    |  2000 | 1200 |1210  |4410 |310    |450    |120    |
    |  1000 |  0   |0     |1000 |500    |0      |0      |
```

field Shift1 wrong because in table trans_lhpdthp there is more than one row.

Maybe you can help tofix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregate `trans_lhpdthp` using a nested query before joining :

replace :

```
FROM
    trans_lhphd a INNER JOIN trans_lhpdthp b ON
        b.IdBukti= a.IdBukti
```

by :

```
FROM
    trans_lhphd a INNER JOIN (
         select
             IdBukti,HasilProduksi,Tanggal,
             sum(QtyProduksi) as QtyProduksi
         from trans_lhpdthp
         group by IdBukti,HasilProduksi,Tanggal)  b ON
        b.IdBukti= a.IdBukti
```